# Set Dynamic SerializedName annotation for Gson data class

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

The response I'm returning from my API call via Retrofit has a dynamic value for each object. I need to be able to edit the value in the @SerializedName annotation with each call.
Here's the JSON response:

> ```
> {
>   "data": {
>     "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20190920_110850.jpg": {
>       "id": "4f7e74d1-afa8-4924-a8ab-ea9360400b",
>       "location": "279dbcd7666b/4f7e74d1-afa8-4924-a8ab-ea9360400b.jpg",
>       "bucket": "challenge-submit"
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Here's my data class:

```
data class UploadLinksResponse(
    @SerializedName("data")
    val data: UploadData
)

data class UploadData(
    @SerializedName("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20190920_110850.jpg")
    val media: MediaLink
)

data class MediaLink(
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id: String,
    @SerializedName("bucket")
    val bucket: String,
    @SerializedName("location")
    val uploadLocation: String
)
```

How can I set the SerializedName for the MediaLink object, which will be a unique value each time I upload?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to parse data as Map, the code below can help for that.

```
data class UploadLinksResponse(
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose 
    val data: Map<String, MediaLink>
)


data class MediaLink(
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id: String,
    @SerializedName("bucket")
    val bucket: String,
    @SerializedName("location")
    val uploadLocation: String
)
```

so you will able to fetch data as a map then your dynamic data will be key and related data will work as a value for that key, then you need to use the iterator to get data from key and value as per key's value.